# Yii register system

Tags: php, yii, user-registration, yii-components

I have this register system that doesn't work. Can you please help me!!

Also I must mention that I am using the [Randomness extention](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/randomness/) .

the Yii error:

```
Property "Users.password2" is not defined.
/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(144)
```

SiteController.php

```
public function actionRegister()
        {
                $model = new Users;
                // collect user input data

                if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='register-form')
                {
                        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                        Yii::app()->end();
                }


                if(isset($_POST['RegsiterForm']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['RegsiterForm']; // set all attributes with post values

                        // NOTE Changes to any $model->value have to be performed BEFORE $model-validate() 
                        // or else it won't save to the database. 

                        // Check if question has a ? at the end

                        // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
                        if($model->validate())
                        {
                                // save user registration
                                $model->save();
                                $this->redirect($this->render('finished',array('model'=>$model))); // Yii::app()->user->returnUrl
                        }
                }
                // display the registration model
                $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));
        }
```

Register.php (The view file, form was generated from Gii)

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'register-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password2'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'password2'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'password2'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'fullname'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'fullname'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'fullname'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'question'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'question'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'question'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'answer'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'answer'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'answer'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row buttons">
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
        </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

user.php (the model)

```
public function rules()
        {
                // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
                // will receive user inputs.
                return array(
                        array('username','length','max'=>16),
                        // convert username to lower case
                        array('username', 'filter', 'filter'=>'strtolower'),
                        array('password','length','max'=>32, 'min'=>6),
                        array('password2','length','max'=>32, 'min'=>6),
                        // compare password to repeated password
                        array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password2'), 
                        array('email, fullname', 'length', 'max'=>128),
                        // make sure email is a valid email
                        array('email','email'),
                        // make sure username and email are unique
                        array('username, email, password, salt', 'unique'), 
                        // convert question to lower case
                        array('question', 'filter', 'filter'=>'strtolower'),
                        array('answer','length','max'=>64),
                        // convert answer to lower case
                        array('answer', 'filter', 'filter'=>'strtolower'),
                        array('privilages, worns, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                        array('privilages','length','max'=>4, 'min'=>1),
                        array('worns','length','max'=>3, 'min'=>0),
                        array('status','length','max'=>2, 'min'=>0),
                        array('username, password, password2, salt, email, fullname, register_date, login_date, privilages, worns, status', 'required'),
                        // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
                        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!extension_loaded('gd')),
                );
        }

 [..........]

        public function beforeSave()
        {
                while ($record2 === null){
                        $salt = Randomness::randomString(32);
                        $record2 = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('salt'=>$salt));
                }
                $pass = hash('sha512', $this->password.$salt);
                $this->salt = $salt;
                $this->password = $pass;
                return true;
        }
```

and UserIdentity.php

```
<?php

/**
 * UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
 * It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
 * data can identity the user.
 */
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
        private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password!==hash('sha512', $this->password.$record->salt))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
                        while ($record2 !== null){
                                $salt = Randomness::randomString(32);
                                $record2 = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('salt'=>$salt));
                        }
                        $record->salt = $salt;
                        $record->password = hash('sha512', $this->password.$salt);
                        $record->save;
            $this->_id=$record->id;
            $this->setState('user_id', $record->id);
                        $this->setState('user_username', $record->username);
                        $this->setState('user_privilages', $record->privilages);
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `password2` doesn't actually exist in the database table.  I presume you're using it simply for validation of the first `password` field, but by trying to create it from the model, you're telling the model to look in the database for that field.

You need to add it as a public property of your user model.